# Call SourceInclude without manually specifying all properties

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm using NEST 1.7 to query Elasticsearch. I'm using `SourceInclude` on a `Get` operation because I only need part of the source back. I've got a DTO class to represent the properties I want to get back from Elasticsearch. However, I need to specify manually all properties params to the `SourceInclude` method.

Here's a minimal repro of what I'm doing:

```
[ElasticType(Name = "productDoc")]
public class Product
{
    [ElasticProperty(Name = "doc_id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Name = "fullname")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Name = "desc")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    // Et cetera...
}

public class SearchRepo
{
    public Product RetrieveProduct(string id)
    {
        IElasticClient client = new ElasticClient();

        var getResponse = client.Get<Product>(p => p
            .Id(id)
            .SourceInclude(
                i => i.Id,
                i => i.Name,
                i => i.Description
                // Et cetera...
            )
        );

        return getResponse.Source;
    }
}
```

This gets labor intensive and error prone if there are many properties on a dto. **I would like to somehow specify that only the properties of my DTO class are included in the source.**

I've tried leaving out the `SourceInclude` call alltogether, hoping NEST would be able to infer what it needed from the generic type argument to `Get`, but inspecting the Elasticsearch request in the debugger seems to tell me the *whole* document is retrieved.

Is there any middle ground with standard NEST functionality? Or do I need to roll my own method to list all dto properties dynamically?

---

PS. I've [asked a similar question (/ feature request) on Github](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1737).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you need to handle generating the list of field names to retrieve yourself. If you do not mention `SourceInclude`, then the entire `_source` will be retrieved. That is the behaviour of Elasticsearch. Nevertheless, Nest will be able to create a `Product` object out of the response if the field names match.